# Lodash Add Object to already sorted Array of Obejct

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, lodash

I am looking for adding an object into an already sorted array of object. So that new array should be sorted after adding the new object into it.

Here is my sorted Array based on object property displayName

```
[
  {
    "id": "06BCCC25",
    "displayName":"Application"

  },
  {
    "id": "39F886D9", 
    "displayName":"Communication"
  },
  {
    "id": "22EA4ED5",
     "displayName":"Device"
  },
  {
    "id": "2F6E5FEA",
     "displayName":"Service"
  },
  {
    "id": "317BF72C", "displayName":"Service02"
  }

]
```

now I want to add

```
{
    "id": "07BSSC25",
    "displayName":"Mail"

  }
```

so after adding it will be placed between 3rd and 4th index.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `_.sortedIndexBy()` for that, see:

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortedIndexBy

For example you could use:

```
array.splice(_.sortedIndexBy(array, value, iteratee), 0, value);
```

where `array` is your array of objects, `value` is the new object to insert and `iteratee` is a function invoked per element that returns the value that you want to sort it by, but it also can be a property name.

So in your case something like this should work:

```
array.splice(_.sortedIndexBy(array, value, 'displayName'), 0, value);
```

Just substitute your array name for `array` and the new object for `value`.

See also this issue on GitHub where it is explained:

- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/537

You might also add a lodash function if you use it a lot, for example:

```
_.insertSorted = (a, v) => a.splice(_.sortedIndex(a, v), 0, v);
_.insertSortedBy = (a, v, i) => a.splice(_.sortedIndexBy(a, v, i), 0, v);
```

And you could use - in your case

```
_.insertSorted(array, value, 'displayName');
```

Comment: Out of interest, would this be more efficient than just pushing the object to the end of the array and then sorting the array?

Answer (score -2):

This was our solution without lodash...

```
const records = [{ name: 'a'}, { name: 'b'}, { name: 'c'}, { name: 'd'}];
const newObjRecord = { name: 'e' };

// inserts into an already sorted array
// it still works, even if the array is empty
// it still works, even if the item should be the last
const inserted = records.some((record, index) => {
    if (record.name > newObjRecord.name) {
        records.splice(index, 0, newObjRecord);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
// if the array is empty or at the very end, insert it at the end
if (!inserted) records.push(newObjRecord);
```